# How to drop rows in one DataFrame based on one similar column in another Dataframe that has a different number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

**I have two DataFrames that are completely dissimilar except for certain values in one particular column:**

```
df
  First  Last   Email             Age
0 Adam   Smith  email1@email.com   30
1 John   Brown  email2@email.com  35
2 Joe    Max    email3@email.com  40
3 Will   Bill   email4@email.com  25
4 Johnny Jacks  email5@email.com  50
```

```
df2
  ID   Location  Contact
0 5435 Austin    email5@email.com
1 4234 Atlanta   email1@email.com
2 7896 Toronto   email3@email.com
```

How would I go about finding the matching values in the Email column of df and the Contact column of df2, and then dropping the whole row in df based on that match?

**Output I'm looking for (index numbering doesn't matter):**

```
df1
  First  Last   Email             Age
1 John   Brown  email2@email.com  35
3 Will   Bill   email4@email.com  25
```

**I've been able to identify matches using a few different methods like:**

Changing the column names to be identical

```
common = df.merge(df2,on=['Email'])
df3 = df[(~df['Email'].isin(common['Email']))]
```

But df3 still shows all the rows from df.

I've also tried:

```
common = df['Email'].isin(df2['Contact'])
df.drop(df[common].index, inplace = True)
```

And again, identifies the matches but df still contains all original rows.

**So the main thing I'm having difficulty with is updating df with the matches dropped or creating a new DataFrame that contains only the rows with dissimilar values when comparing the Email column from df and the Contact column in df2.** Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is df3? To get the output you pasted it's enough to do: df[~df['Email'].isin(df2['Contact'])]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments(@Arkadiusz), it is enough to filter your data using the following

```
df3 = df[(~df['Email'].isin(df2.Contact))].copy()
print(df3)
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid error. I assumed it wasn't working because I saw the same number for the last index. Once I reset the index it showed the number I was expecting....